# Problems solving equation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x,y) \in (0,1)^2$. How many solutions does this equation have?
$$\sqrt3 \cdot x = \cos(xy)$$

I really have no idea on how to get to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with known trigonometric lines :

- $\frac{\sqrt{3}}2=\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$ this gives $x=\frac 12$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{3}$.
- $1=\cos(0)$ this gives $x=\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}$ and $y=0$

But in both cases $y\notin]0,1[$ so these are not valid solutions.

The feeling is that if $x$ get smaller, $y$ will increase even more, but when  $x$ get larger there may be solutions.

Let study $\displaystyle y=\frac{\arccos(\sqrt{3}\,x)}{x}$ for $x\in]0,\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}]$.

$\displaystyle y'=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{1-3x^2}}-\frac{\arccos(\sqrt{3}\,x)}{x^2}<0$ the expression is complicated, but the sign is easy to determine since $\arccos$ is positive in this interval.

In particular $y(x)$ is strictly $\searrow$ on $]0,\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}]$.

Near zero : $y\sim \frac{\pi}{2x}$ so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}y(x)=+\infty$

$y(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})=\sqrt{3}\arccos(1)=0$

Since the function is continuous and monotonic, there is an unique $\alpha\in]0,\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}[$ such that $y(\alpha)=1$.

Dichotomy gives $\alpha\simeq 0.50522$.

> Finally $\sqrt{3}\,x=\cos(xy)$ for $(x,y)\in]0,1[^2$ has $1$ unique $y$ solution for every $x\in]\alpha,\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}[$

Answer (score 0):

The graph suggests that there are infinitely many solutions. For $x\in[0.51,0.57]$, there exists $y\in(0,1)$ such that $\sqrt{3}x=\cos(xy)$.

Say for $x=0.52$, $\sqrt{3}x\approx 0.9006664$ and $1=\cos 0>\cos(xy)>\cos x\approx0.8678192$. There must be a $y\in(0,1)$ such that $\sqrt{3}x=\cos(xy)$.

[image]